# unsigned overflow with modulus operator in C

Tags: c, overflow, unsigned, modulus

i encountered a bug in some c code i wrote, and while it was relatively easy to fix, i want to be able to understand the issue underlying it better.  essentially what happened is i had two unsigned integers (uint32_t, in fact) that, when the modulus operation was applied, yielded the unsigned equivalent of a negative number, a number that had been wrapped and was thus "big".  here is an example program to demonstrate:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  uint32_t foo = -1;
  uint32_t u   = 2048;
  uint64_t ul  = 2048;

  fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", foo);
  fprintf(stderr, "%u\n", foo);
  fprintf(stderr, "%lu\n", ((foo * 2600000000) % u));
  fprintf(stderr, "%ld\n", ((foo * 2600000000) % u));
  fprintf(stderr, "%lu\n", ((foo * 2600000000) % ul));
  fprintf(stderr, "%lu\n", foo % ul);

  return 0;

}
```

this produces the following output, on my x86_64 machine:

```
-1
4294967295
18446744073709551104
-512
1536
2047
```

1536 is the number i was expecting, but (uint32_t)(-512) is the number i was getting, which, as you might imagine, threw things off a bit.

so, i guess my question is this:  why does a modulus operation between two unsigned numbers, in this case, produce a number that is greater than the divisor (i.e. a negative number)?  is there a reason this behavior is preferred?

Comment: 2600000000 is an int (or maybe a 64-bit int - long or long long), which may have caused the result of the multiplication to become a (signed) long. What platform are you on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason is that the compiler is interpreting the `2600000000` literal as a signed 64-bit number, since it does not fit into a signed 32-bit int. If you replace the number with `2600000000U`, you should get the result you expect.

Comment: Actually OP invoked UB by passing the wrong format strings to `printf`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a reference handy, but I'm pretty sure when you do that multiplication, it promotes them to `int64_t`, because it needs to coerce the two multiplicands to a signed integral type. Try `2600000000u` instead of `2600000000`....